# Dynamically add group of fields in magento while creating products

Tags: php, magento, dynamic, field

I am creating a tour portal in magento 1.8.
The thing I need is to add a group of fields included in the itinerary like place of departure and time according to the no. of days specified for the tour.

eg. If i specify the tour duration to be 2 days i should get 2 sets of the above fields grouped as day 1 and day 2.

How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think Magento provide any feature as desired by you, you either need to create custom module where you can provide a list of all products and then add/edit/delete the groups on day basis.

Another approach to start can be using different attribute sets for different days tour, and then add no of attributes needed in each attribute set.

Hope this will help in starting the development.

Comment: Thanks, that does help. I would prefer the first option as the second option would be limiting, which i would prefer to avoid. Are there any existing examples similar to this or that can point in the right direction?